# Work flow for git after pull request

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and have come up against a scenario I am unfamiliar with.

The scenario is this.

1. Cloned repo
2. Made changes
3. Committed Changes
4. Created Pull Request in origin/my-new-feature
5. Deleted local branch my-new-feature
6. Made more changes
7. Created PRs for them as well.
8. I now have to make slight changes to my code in the first PR.

After reading a few articles I believe this would be the way?

- get checkout -b my-new-feature
- git cherry-pick --hash of first PR commit--
- *Make changes*
- git push origin/my-new-feature
- *Go back to my latest commit and continue working*

Is this the best workflow or am I missing something. I am very new to git.

Comment: I think Ryan's answer is correct. Have a look at https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should've kept your first `my-new-feature` branch. It's best practice to keep these branches around until the pull request is closed or merged.

So to get it back you would do:

1. `git fetch` -- to ensure you have the latest branches and their latest commits
2. `git checkout origin/my-new-feature -b my-new-feature`

This will then restore the my-new-feature branch on your local machine. Add as many commits as you wish to this branch, then push it again with:

3. `git push` or perhaps `git push origin my-new-feature`. Whichever works.